# OpenTk rotations matrices

Tags: rotation, opentk

What is difference between the two rotation matrices? 
I do not understand why the result is different between rotationxyz and rotxyz?

```
Matrix4 rotationXYZ = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(5) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(5) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(5);
Matrix4 rotXYZ = Matrix4.Identity;
Matrix4.CreateRotationX(5, out rotXYZ);
Matrix4.CreateRotationY(5, out rotXYZ);
Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(5, out rotXYZ);`
```

Answer (score 1):

The method Matrix4.CreateRotation#(5, out rotXYZ) build new rotXYZ matrix.
I.e. you three times overwrite rotXYZ.